# Mounting a laptop image onto a tablet - is it possible?

Tags: windows-8, laptop, 64-bit, iso-image

I replacing one of my laptops with a tablet. I want to take an image of the laptop and install the image onto my tablet.

The laptop is a Lenovo E540 64-bit running Windows 10. The tablet is a HP Stream 7 32-bit, also running Win 10

To effect the change, I was going to reimage as per the following sequence:
1.  Image the laptop.
2.  Mount image onto spare hard drive.
3.  Boot the spare hard drive on laptop and remove additional users, some unnecessary programs (ie, hardware related) and downgrade from Windows 64-bit to 32-bit.
4.  Image this OS and mount to tablet.

Is there anything I'm missing from this, or can anyone see any potential distasters looming? I'm imaging to a spare hard drive so that I still have a working, untouched OS on the primary hard drive should it all go wrong.  I have a little experiencing with working with ISO's, etc, but nowhere near enough to be fully confident about this.

If anyone's got any experience or any comments that could help, I'd be really glad to hear them.

Comment: Problems may include missing hardware drivers, windows licensing, ...

Comment: ok, if I checked on the tablet now, get a list of the hardware drivers required and then install them on the spare hard drive before imaging, hopefully that will sort out hardware, good point.  Regards windows licensing, I've never had a problem with it before...

Comment: If you have an OEM licence you can't transfer it to another computer ...

Comment: Ok.  Laptop is retail copy and have already transferred the OS once so guessing it's gonna be ok.  I think I'll go ahead and try.

Comment: <shrug> I am not a lawyer ... but that article refers to buying an OEM licence key and installing it yourself. That is not the same as transferring an existing licence.

Answer (score 0):

The process of downgrading involves making a backup, installing a fresh install of 32 bit windows, then restoring the backup. To simplify what you are doing, don't do the downgrade on the laptop. Just backup your data from your 64 bit version, then restore to the tablet's existing 32 bit windows.

So your steps will be:
1. image the laptop drive to the spare drive
2. boot to the clone in order to edit out users etc. that you don't want on the tablet
3. back-up the data from the clone
4. restore the backup to the existing 32 bit windows on the tablet.
Optionally you can give the tablet a fresh install of windows before step 4.

Now since the tablet already has a copy of windows, you don't need to transfer the license from the laptop to it. You are only transferring the user data, not the OS.